# How can I refresh MySQL without restarting it?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm new to MySQL.When I make a change in my SQL workbench, for example I change something in my settings why doesn't it a effect MySQL right away. only when i restart MySQL does it effect the transaction.
I tried doing Ctrl & R, but that doesn't work. It brings up Reverse Engineer Database.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql reads it's settings only on startup so you will need something to stop and restart the mysql server service.  You might be able to do it via batch file if you have admin permissions.